# At android google map v2 api, how to find a nearest point from my server DB

Tags: android, algorithm, google-maps, nearest-neighbor

I have developed an android app which marks some information with google map api.

But I don't have an idea for an algorithm of searching closest points compared with custom DB coordinates.

Here is a hypothesis.
1) The DB server has 1,000 data.
2) Each 1,000 data have a coordinate[lati & longi] of a some nation.
3) The app shows & set markers of top 20 nearest points, compared with current users coordinate.

I have two simple ideas for solving this problem. but both of them are not effective.

A) Look for all of data in DB. then compare, pick top 20 points.
; it must select whole 1,000 data...

B) Insert a detail address categories into each 1,000 data. (state, city, post# & etc..)
then get detail address of current location, and compare only the specified address categories.
; looks good but, there's a boundary problem. if you are at a place between "A" city & "B" city, it only find a points of "A"s or "B"s.

Is there any solutions or ideas?

Comment: at 1) you say 1000 and on 2) 10000. typo?

Comment: A.... a mistake. Sorry. I edited that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to put the data in a spatial database such as [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/), and execute a spatial query that performs a nearest neighbour search.

From http://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/:

> PostGIS (the development code in the source repository) now has the ability to do index-assisted nearest neighbour searching... You will need PostgreSQL 9.1 and the PostGIS source code from the repository, but this is what a nearest neighbour search looks like:
>
> ```
>    SELECT name, gid
>    FROM geonames
>    ORDER BY geom <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-90,40),4326)
>    LIMIT 10;
> ```
>
> Note the magic <-> operator in the ORDER BY clause. This is where the magic occurs. The <-> is a “distance” operator, but it only makes use of the index when it appears in the ORDER BY clause. Between putting the operator in the ORDER BY and using a LIMIT to truncate the result set, we can very very quickly (less than 10ms on a 2M record table, in this case) get the 10 nearest points to our test point.

There are spatial databases for Android such as [Spatialite](https://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/) if you require the data to be stored locally.

Comment: thanks, that's what I want it.
but I found other way. link here : http://www.elevatedcode.com/2009/03/06/speeding-up-location-based-searches.html

Comment: Yes, MySQL with spatial extensions would work too.  Spatial support in Postgres has been around longer than in MySQL, and my understanding is that PostGIS is a more robust spatial solution than MySQL.